# Redirection to a Page in HTML Python Flask Arduino

Tags: python, http, flask, arduino

I am working on a project that uses a HTML page to control an Arduino.
Arduino has a menu that is accessed by sending a character through the serial port (USB).
The problem is that python will send too many characters when using the web page.
So how can I make the href form to direct me back to the home page after it completes the action? Also for some reason, it can't find the CSS file even if the address is correct.
The hosting is done trough python flask
HTTP code:
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>GPIO Control</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href='../static/Style.css'/>
   </head>

   <body>
                <h1> Commands </h1>
<h2>
Auto On ==>
<a href="/action1" class="Auto On">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Auto OFF ==>
<a href="/action2" class="Auto OFF">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Fan ON ==>
<a href="/action3" class="Fan ON">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Fan OFF ==>
<a href="/action4" class="Fan OFF">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Pump OFF ==>
<a href="/action5" class="Pump OFF">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Pump ON ==>
<a href="/action6" class="Pump ON">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Window Open ==>
<a href="/action7" class="Window Open">TURN ON</a>

</h2>
<h2>
Window Colse ==>
<a href="/action8" class="Window Colse">TURN ON</a>


   </body>
</html>
'''
```

Python code :
'''

```
import serial
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    templateData = {
    'title' : 'Greenhouse'
    }
    return render_template('index.html',**templateData )
@app.route("/<action>")
def action(action):
    if action == 'action1':
        ser.write('a'.encode())
    if action == 'action2':
        ser.write('m'.encode())
    if action == 'action3':
        ser.write('b'.encode())
    if action == 'action4':
        ser.write('c'.encode())
    if action == 'action5':
        ser.write('d'.encode())
    if action == 'action6':
        ser.write('e'.encode())
    if action == 'action7':
        ser.write('f'.encode())
    if action == 'action8':
        ser.write('g'.encode())
    if action == 'action9':
        ser.write('h'.encode())
    if action == 'action10':
        ser.write('i'.encode())
    templateData= {
    'title' : 'Greenhouse'
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600, timeout=1)
    ser.flush()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = 8080, debug = True)
```

'''

Comment: "it can't find the CSS file"... use jinja template `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">`. BTW, are you sure you name your style.css with Capital S?

Comment: "redirect"... `return redirect(url_for('index'))`

Comment: The problem might not be your Flask or html, but your Arduino code, but you didn't provide your arduino code.